# When i return type HttpResponseMessage the example value and model is empty in swagger ui

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I use .net framework and the nuget package Swashbuckle.
I have the controller with the method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("getProductById")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetProductById([FromUri] int id)
    {
        Product response = service.GetProductById(id);
        if (response != null)
        {

            return Request.CreateResponse<Product>(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not Found");
    }
```

The SwaggerConfig is

```
    [assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace ProductsApp
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "ProductsApp");
                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    {

                    });
        }
    }
}
```

But now when I run the project and the url localhost:61342/swagger/ui/index i have the problem that example values and model is empty.
https://prnt.sc/o7wlqe

When i modify the method to return only the product is ok.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("getProductById")]
    public Product GetProductById([FromUri] int id)
    {
        Product response = service.GetProductById(id);
        return response;
    }
```

https://prnt.sc/o7wp4d

How i can combine to return the HttrResponseMessage  and to have the example values and model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare the response type via the `ResponseTypeAttribute` attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("getProductById")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
public HttpResponseMessage GetProductById([FromUri] int id)
{
    Product response = service.GetProductById(id);
    if (response != null)
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse<Product>(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
    }
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not Found");
}
```